# Regex to remove underscore and everything after underscore

Tags: apex

I have string

string s = ADSS1001_101

How to format that to get 
only ADSS1001

I want to remove underscore and everything after underscore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of possible ways to do it. One of this below.

```
string s = 'ADSS1001_101';
String[] answer = s.split('_');
system.debug('answer' + answer[0]);
```

Comment: I was able to figure it
string s1 = 'ADSS1001_101'  
        string s2 ='_';  
        if(s1.contains(s2)){  
            string s3 = s1.substringBefore('_');